# file upload progress bar without jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

We are trying to add file upload progress bar without using ajax and jquery. But not find  useful tutorial on google.

This is our basic code

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
<input name="name" type="text" />
<input name="user_type" type="hidden" />
<input name="address" type="text" />
<!-- more fields -->
<input name="uploaded" type="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

In upload.php we are doing lots of processing and redirect to several pages as per user input.

When we use jquery then control is not going to upload.php and not redirecting to pages.

How we can add progress bar without using jquery?

Here is jquery code which we tried

```
(function() {

var bar = $('.bar');
var percent = $('.percent');
var status = $('#status');

$('form').ajaxForm({
    beforeSend: function() {
    status.empty();
    var percentVal = '0%';
    bar.width(percentVal)
    percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
    var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
    bar.width(percentVal)
    percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    complete: function(xhr) {
     bar.width("100%");
    percent.html("100%");
    status.html(xhr.responseText);
    }
});

  <div class="progress">
    <div class="bar"></div >
    <div class="percent">0%</div >
</div>

<div id="status"></div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to put the HTML `<div class="progress">...` below your jquery code? It should be up by the form.

Comment: we dont want to use     <div class="progress">...   of jquery because if we use it then control is not going to upload.php.

Comment: So do you want to make an ajax call, or redirect? If you do ajax, it's done in the background, any redirects the server does, is not done in the browser etc.

Comment: Let me explain again. When we click on submit button, page will redirect to upload.php for form submission process( like file upload and other tasks), Mean while we want to show progress bar on page. 
So i think in this we cant use ajax.

Comment: @adeneo Sorry, didn't get you.

Comment: Was it unclear? The code you currently have uploads files with ajax and measure the progress of that. If you want a real form submit, that uploads the files the regular way, you won't be able to just stick on a progressbar. You can use ajax, but you'd need a different script on the server, that measures the progress serverside, and then do polling clientside to update that progress etc. It gets somewhat complicated pretty fast, but that's how we did it before ajax uploads were available.

Answer (score -1):

Your best bet is probably to have a separate PHP file like `process-upload.php` that processes the file upload and saves any variables you want to the `$_SESSION` then you can do something like this:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="process-upload.php" method="POST">
<input name="name" type="text" />
<input name="user_type" type="hidden" />
<input name="address" type="text" />
<!-- more fields -->
<input name="uploaded" type="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="bar"></div >
    <div class="percent">0%</div >
</div>
```

And the javascript:

```
var bar = $('.bar');
var percent = $('.percent');
var status = $('#status');

$('form').ajaxForm({
    beforeSend: function() {
        status.empty();
        var percentVal = '0%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
        var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    success: function() {
        var percentVal = '100%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    complete: function() {
        window.location.replace("upload.php")
    }
});
```

Then you can retrieve your variables from `$_SESSION` on `upload.php`